# How to Split String into three parts in C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a string like **"123456 abcdefgh ijkl mno 78903 "**

Now, I have to split into three parts i.e

1. string1- "123456"
2. string2  - "abcdefgh ijkl mno"
3. string3 - "78903"

Comment: Hello User, There are two solution posted below waiting for your response. You need to accept that one of them if it meets your requirement. If you are new to Stack Ovrflow, Kindly have a look at here [How To Accept An Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

So your common splitter is a space, which essencially lets you do this:

```
public void Example()
{
    var content = "123456 abcdefgh ijkl mno 78903";
    var parts = content.Split(' '); // split on spaces

    var string1 = parts.First();
    var string3 = parts.Last();
    var theRest = content
        .Replace(parts.First(), "")
        .Replace(parts.Last(), "");
}
```

What I basically did over here is to split the original string on space, so I have an array of parts, then I get the first and the last part, and finally, I remove those from the content to provide what is left.

Comment: Please clarify How can I do this ?

Comment: what if the size of three fields are varchar(50)?